# Сreating a file in memory

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

There is a question.
I need to put a separate ini file into the archive.
BUT I don't want to collect and store this file on disk.

Is it possible to collect a file and place it in an archive without saving it to disk?

Now the archive is going like this.

```
var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        var filepaths = Directory.GetFiles(setting.DirMicroSip);
        using (var archive = new ZipArchive(memoryStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
        {
            foreach(string filepath in filepaths)
            {
                string filename = Path.GetFileName(filepath);
                var entry = archive.CreateEntry(filename);
                using (var file = File.OpenRead(Path.Combine(setting.DirMicroSip, filename)))
                using (var entryStream = entry.Open())
                {
                    await file.CopyToAsync(entryStream);
                }
            }
        }

        memoryStream.Position = 0;
        response.Content = new StreamContent(memoryStream);
        response.Content.Headers.ContentLength = memoryStream.Length;
        response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
        {
            FileName = "Archive.zip"
        };
        response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/zip");
        return response;
```

And ini on the disk like this.

```
    var ini = new IniFile("C:/arh/MicroSIP_test.ini");
    ini.Write("accountId", "1", "Settings");
    ini.Write("singleMode", "1", "Settings");...
```

Help me please

Comment: using (var m = new MemoryStream())
{
    {
        using (var archive = new ZipArchive(m, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
        {
            foreach (/* enumerate your sources*/)
            {
                entryName = // set a name
                string text = // set content
                var demoFile = archive.CreateEntry(entryName);
                using (var entryStream = demoFile.Open())
                using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(entryStream))
                    streamWriter.Write(text);
            }
        }

Comment: ..

        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
        {
            m.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            m.CopyTo(fileStream);
        }
    }
}

Comment: Take a look at [FileStreamResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.filestreamresult.-ctor?view=aspnetcore-6.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-mvc-filestreamresult-ctor(system-io-stream-microsoft-net-http-headers-mediatypeheadervalue)). That takes a arbitrary stream as input, and should be possible to return as the result.

Comment: Note that there is no real way to create a "file in memory". You create streams, or in some cases, spans. So whatever API your using needs to accept stream/span. First party libraries are quite good at this, but some third party libraries are not as well designed.

Comment: @TaW If you have an answer, why not post it?

Comment: I don't post answers here any longer. m is the memorystream, define at the very start. watch the braces..

Comment: Take a look at MemoryMappedFiles https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/memory-mapped-files